# Django one to many between legacy tables with no PK to FK relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using legacy DB tables that I have no control over the tables design.

Table A has an auto_gen ID field as follows:
**Table DRAWER (One Side), Table FOLDER (Many Side)**

```
class Drawer(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
    fld1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column='FLD1')
    fld2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column='FLD2')
    fld3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column='FLD3')

    def __str__(self):
        field_values = []
        for field in self._meta.get_fields():
            field_values.append(str(getattr(self, field.name, '')))
        return ' '.join(field_values)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = u'"MySchema"."DRAWER"'




class Folder(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
    fld1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column='FLD1')
    fld4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column='FLD4')
    fld5 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_column='FLD5')
    drawer = models.ForeignKey(to=Drawer, related_name='Drawer.fld1+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)

    def __str__(self):
        field_values = []
        for field in self._meta.get_fields():
            field_values.append(str(getattr(self, field.name, '')))
        return ' '.join(field_values)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = u'"MySchema"."FOLDER"'
```

The ID fields are numeric auto gen.   I am trying to use Djano models to establish a one to many relation between Tables DRAWER and FOLDER ***using fld1***.  fld1 is unique in Drawer, and many in Folder. I have done this in Java, but so far, it seems that Django won't allow it.  Django seems to expect that one side must be a PK?  I do realize that Django has many to one (instead of one to many) and followed the documentations ... but it is not working.  Please advise if there is a way to do this in Django models framework.

The end result I am looking for in the rest service is something like below, which is what I get from the current JAVA Hibernate Data Rest Service:

```
{
"ID": 1234,
"FLD1": "xxxxxxxx",
"FLD2": "wertt",
"FLD3": "rtyuio",
folder:[
{
"ID": 5645,
"FLD1": "xxxxxxxx",
"FLD4": "zzzzzzz",
"FLD5": "cccccccc",
},
{
"ID": 5645,
"FLD1": "xxxxxxxx",
"FLD4": "rrrrrrr",
"FLD5": "cccccuuuuuuuuuuccc",
}
.
.
]
```

I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: What did you write until now, where are your models, many to one or one to many is same thing

Comment: Hello, I updated the post per your suggestion.  Thank you